# Как подключить шрифт в css

Tags: html, css, шрифты

Сайт https://4coders.pro/Unbrokenteam/index.html

Подключал шрифт по этим статьям:
https://www.cat-in-web.ru/podklyuchenie-shriftov-v-css/
https://moguta.ru/blog/delaem-internet-magazin-vmeste/kak-podklyuchit-shrift-na-sajt-v-css

В папку fonts на хостинге закачал Open Sans https://cloud.mail.ru/public/DsqH/bHBMnPvMv

В css прописал:

```css
@font-face {
font-family: 'Open Sans';
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
src: url(/fonts/OpenSans-Regular.eot); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
src: url(/fonts/OpenSans-Regular.eot#iefix) format('embedded-opentype'),
url(/fonts/OpenSans-Regular.woff) format('woff'),
url(/fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf) format('truetype'),
url(/fonts/OpenSans-Regular.svg#OpenSans-Regular) format('svg');
}
@font-face {
font-family: 'Open Sans';
font-weight: 700;
font-style: normal;
src: url(/fonts/OpenSans-Bold.eot); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
src: url(/fonts/OpenSans-Bold.eot) format('embedded-opentype'),
url(/fonts/OpenSans-Bold.woff) format('woff'),
url(/fonts/OpenSans-Bold.ttf) format('truetype'),
url(/fonts/OpenSans-Bold.svg#OpenSans-Bold) format('svg');
}
```

и применил здесь:

```css
.myDivBlueBackground{
background-color: #FEE3B0;
padding: 20px;
font-family: "Open Sans";
}
.myDivWhiteBackground{
background-color: white;
padding: 20px;
font-family: "Open Sans";
}
```

Я все правильно сделал?

Comment: А он применился?

Answer (score 0):

По всей видимости - да,

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

можете сами себя проверять, клик на этот значок и потом курсор наводите на элемент, появляется подсказка
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]